# MT4 Data Feeder: Need to send UTF-8 formated news to specific group only

Tags: mt4

I am trying to send news to clients, through a specific Data Feeder. The news are in UTF-8 format, and they can only be sent to the clients that their platform can show them.

So, my question is there any way of sending the news only to these clients? The NewsSend() method of the MT4ManagerAPI sends the news to all the clients. I just want to send the news to clients with a specific language set in the terminal or, at least, to a specific group only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you would have to create a manger that only sees that particular group of users. Then I believe, if you log in with that manger to the api, the connection will only be able to interact with these users. If you NewsSend on that connection only those users should see it.